# Extract columns from Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an Excel file with the ff: row/col structure

```
ID   English   Spanish   French
 1   Hello     Hilo      Halu
 2   Hi        Hye       Ghi
 3   Bus       Buzz      Bas
```

I would like to read the Excel file, extract the row and col values, and create 3 new files base on the columns English, Spanish, and French.

So I would have something like:

English File:

```
"1" = "Hello"
"2" = "Hi"
"3" = "Bus"
```

I've been using xlrd. I can open, read, and print the contents of the file. However, this is what I get using this command (with the Excel file already open):

```
for index in xrange(0,2):
    theWord = '\n' + str(sh.col_values(index, start_rowx=index, end_rowx=1)) + '=' + str(sh.col_values(index+1, start_rowx=index, end_rowx = 1))
    print theWord
```

OUTPUT:

```
[u'Parameter/Variable/Key/String']=[u'ENGLISH'] <-- is this a list?, didn't the str() use to strip it out?
```

What's the **u** doing there?
How can I remove the square brackets?

Comment: So none of the answers below addresses your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `u` means it is a unicode string, it gets put there when you call `str()`. If you write the string out to a file it wont be there. What you are getting is 1 row from the column. It's because you are using `end_rowx=1` it returns a list with one element.

Try getting the column value lists:

```
ids = sh.col_values(0, start_rowx=1)
english = sh.col_values(1, start_rowx=1)
spanish = sh.col_values(2, start_rowx=1)
french = sh.col_values(3, start_rowx=1)
```

and then you can `zip` them into tuple lists:

```
english_with_IDS = zip(ids, english)
spanish_with_IDS = zip(ids, spanish)
french_with_IDS = zip(ids, french)
```

Which are in the form:

```
("1", "Hello"),("2", "Hi"), ("3", "Bus")
```

If you want to print the pairs:

```
for id, word in english_with_IDS:
       print id + "=" + word
```

`col_values` returns a list of column values, if you want single values you can call `sh.cell_value(rowx, cellx)`.

Comment: it resembles a basis for my solution, likewise, you've answered the question of 'u's existence in the output.

Answer (score 4):

```
import xlrd

sh = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls').sheet_by_index(0)
english = open("english.txt", 'w')
spanish = open("spanish.txt", 'w')
french = open("french.txt", 'w')
try:
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        english.write(str(rownum)+ " = " +str(sh.cell(rownum, 0).value)+"\n")
        spanish.write(str(rownum)+ " = " +str(sh.cell(rownum, 1).value)+"\n")
        french.write(str(rownum)+ " = " +str(sh.cell(rownum, 2).value)+"\n")
finally:
    english.close()
    spanish.close()
    french.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.ExcelFile('test.xls').parse('Sheet1', index_col=0) # reads file

In [3]: df.index = df.index.map(int)

In [4]: for col in df.columns:
   ...:     column = df[col]
   ...:     column.to_csv(column.name, sep='=')  # writes each column to a file                                                    
   ...:                                          # with filename == column name

In [5]: !cat English  # English file content
1=Hello
2=Hi
3=Bus
```

Comment: I didn't tried this, given the fact xlrd/xlwt can do almost all the stuff I need but I think its worth mentioning.